# how to get the value of an input and put it into an onclick

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this problem, had a function on ajax that needs lat and lng variables, so function test(lat,lng)...

That's the HTML simple code:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Serveis de geocodificació</legend>

Latitud:<br><input type="text" id="lat" value="42.3600077"/><br>
Longitud:<br><input type="text" id="lng" value="1.4579696"/><br>

<input type="button" value="Veure dades" onclick=primerSelect()/>
<input type="button" value="Veure coordenades"/><br>

Carrer:<br><input type="text" id="car"/><br>
Ciutat:<br><input type="text" id="ciu"/><br>
Pais:<br><input type="text" id="pai"/><br>
CP:<br><input type="text" id="cod"/><br>

</fieldset>
```

So, the problems resides in the onclick, how can i get the value of the id's lat and lng? and put it into the onclick function? like that:

```
onclick=primerSelect(id lat.value, id lng.value)
```

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `onclick`, but rather use an event listener.  Your code will be a bit easier to use this way.  At any rate, You could use

```
onclick="primerSelect(document.getElementById('lat').value,
    document.getElementById('lng').value)"
```

Comment: +1 - But please, use an event listener! Looking at a page full of inline JS causes mild insanity.

Comment: I create a new question, maybe you can help me on it too? thx for all

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
function primerSelect(){
    var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
    var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;

    // Here goes your code...
}
```